# use of the idiom "in earnest"

Tags: idioms

Can I use the idiom "in earnest" as follows: "I strongly believe that XX program will offer me the perfect chance for my specialisation in XX to begin in earnest.

Comment: Whether you can use it depends on if that's what you mean. It's grammatical. It may or may not be appropriate depending on what meaning you are trying to convey.

Answer (score 1):

It would be correct as the  idiom is used here in the first  dictionary meaning.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20earnest):

***in earnest*** 
(an idiom)

1: in an earnest or serious way

The search began in earnest when the police arrived.
After light showers during the day, it began to rain in earnest in the evening.
It's hard to tell if he's making this proposal in earnest.

2: not fooling : serious and sincere
We thought he was joking at first, but then we realized that he was in earnest.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20earnest